# jQuery live doesn't appear to bind click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

The dynamically added links (classnames `.divToggle` and `.removeDiv`) only function if clicked twice the first time. What is preventing them from working properly right away?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // adds click event to links.
    $('a.divToggle').live('click', function(event) {
        // Toggles the visibility of divs.
        event.preventDefault;
        $(this).toggle(function(){
                $(this).next(".divToToggle").slideUp("slow");
                $(this).text("show[+]");
        },
        function(){
                $(this).next(".divToToggle").slideDown("slow");
                $(this).text("hide[-]");
        });     
    });
    
    // used to remove divs from the page.
    $("a.removeDiv").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault;
        $(this).parent().prev("a").prev("h2").remove();
        $(this).parent().prev("a").remove();
        $(this).parent().next("br").remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();  
    }); 
    
    // Used to add new divs to the page.
    $(".addDiv").click(function(){
        $("<h2>Title Area</h2><a href='#' class='divToggle'>hide[-]</a>"
        + "<div class='divToToggle'><a href='#' class='removeDiv'>Remove this div</a>"
        + "<ul><li>List element 1</li><li>List element 2</li>"
        + "<li>List element 3</li></ul></div><br />").insertBefore($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery and is this browser-specific or everywhere? I've had trouble with live() click events in IE (in previous versions of jQuery; not sure about 1.4).

Comment: Jquery 1.4.1 using Firefox and Chrome for Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(...).toggle` doesn't do anything straight away. It just binds click events to the selected elements, so that in the future clicking causes one of the two functions to be called. So the first click does nothing but set up the toggle event handler. The second click actually calls the toggle event handler. (And also adds *another* toggle event handler! So the third click calls *two* toggle event handlers, and so on.)

`.toggle` is an alternative to `.click` binding, not something you would (normally) use inside a `.click` event handler.

There is no ‘live’ version of `toggle`, but you can write one yourself, eg.:

```
function livetoggle(selector, f0, f1) {
    $(selector).live('click', function(event) {
        var t= $(this).data('livetoggle');
        $(this).data('livetoggle', !t);
        (t? f1 : f0).call(this, event);
    });
}


livetoggle('a.divToggle', function() {
    ...
}, function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This works for the first link added to the page, subsequent links still need to be clicked twice.

Comment: Thanks to your help it's very close. The behavior I get now is that if  you add the group, then add a second group. Click the link to hide the first group, then click the link to hide the second group you need to click the second link twice.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Yes, I done a mistake. :-) Edited answer to fix the `livetoggle` implementation — try that one.

Comment: I tried this after the alterations and it works, however I went with my code below because I have a better understanding of how it works. You get the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but it is because you have event.preventDefault; before all other code?  I normally use this as the last statement in my function.

Like I said it's a long shot but worth a try!

Have you tried showing an javascript alert or using Firebugs log window to see if the event is being fired the first time?  Maybe it's being fired but not doing what you expect and something else is causing it to fail?

Comment: The `preventDefault` doesn't do anything anyway, because it's not actually called (missing `()` after it).

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i ended up with. Seems to work ok.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// adds click event to links.
$('a.divToggle').live('click', function() {
   var testText = $(this).text();
   if(testText == 'hide[-]') {
    $(this).next('.divToToggle').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).text('show[+]');
   } else {
    $(this).next('.divToToggle').slideDown('slow');
    $(this).text('hide[-]');
   }
})

// used to remove divs from the page.
$('a.removeDiv').live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().prev('a').prev('h2').remove();
    $(this).parent().prev('a').remove();
    $(this).parent().next('br').remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});

// Used to add new divs to the page.
$('.addDiv').click(function(){
    $("<h2>Title Area</h2><a href='#' class='divToggle'>hide[-]</a>"
    + "<div class='divToToggle'><a href='#' class='removeDiv'>Remove this div</a>"
    + "<ul><li>List element 1</li><li>List element 2</li>"
    + "<li>List element 3</li></ul></div><br />").insertBefore($(this));
    return false;
});
```

});